# Chi-square test for interaction

Tags: regression, chi-squared-test, interaction, binary-data

I want to look at the interaction between two independent variables on a binary dependent variable. I can't use a binary logistic regression because I have a small sample size. Can I do this using a chi-square test instead?

Comment: how small is small? how many "successes" and "failures" does your outcome variable have?

Comment: The DV is the number of people who signed up for a follow up study. 42 said yes and 10 said no

Comment: As Maarten Buis was hinting about, a chi-squared test likes to have at least 5 samples in each group. As an alteranative, there is also a Cochran-Mantel-Haenszel test.